# How to redirected to the main page using an elevated button on alert dialog without clicking on the button?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to redirected to the main page using an elevated button on alert dialog without clicking on the button?
I just want to hover the mouse on the button and it will do the specific action and also redirected to the main page without clicking on the button that will appear on alert dialog box.

How to redirected to the main page using an elevated button on alert dialog without clicking on the button?
I just want to hover the mouse on the button and it will do the specific action and also redirected to the main page without clicking on the button that will appear on alert dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **onHover** method of your Button class.

Check documentation example of [ElevatedButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButton-class.html) page

```
onHover → ValueChanged<bool>?
Called when a pointer enters or exits the button response area.
final, inherited
```

Comment: I want to go to specific page in flutter when clicking on the button.